# How to javaconfig in spring 3.2 mapping static resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the next project structure:

```
+MyApp
|
+-+src
  |
  +-+main 
    |
    +-> java
    |
    +-> resources
    |
    +-+ webapp
      |
      +-> resources ( img, css, js)
      |
      +-> WEB-INF ( views )
```

My configuration file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.spring"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
   ...
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
   {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
   ...
}
```

When I try to load css file (), I'll get some.css wasn't found.

I tried to build https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web.git (step 6). It has the same problem with static resources.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer for my question.

I use thymeleaf template engine. In this case, I need write the next:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<html>
   <head>
     <link th:href="@{/resources/css/some.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>
     <img th:src="@{/resources/img/some.jpg}" />
   </body>
</html>
```

That construction will creat url like **url** + *web app name* + **uri to static resource**